# Bootstrap dropdown with two-way data binding for Angular 2

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I've been trying to find an API for making custom bootstrap dropdowns using ngModel. So far, I've already tried to use the dropdown from Valor Software's [ngx-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) (formerly ng2-boostrap) and also their [ng2-select](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/) API.

The ngx-bootstrap dropdown didn't offer 2-way data binding. The ng2-select, at first looked like it was set up to do so, but I wasn't able to get that to work. I found [an issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/issues/232) that this feature is missing.

Am I missing something? Does anyone know of a solution for this? I'm out of ideas. Any examples out there of a dropdown working with ngModel?

Comment: This is the one I've used: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown?

Comment: ...Actually, @ThinkingMedia, that is Angular 1.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova, that is not bootstrap and tries to funnel people to their paid version...